# How to access MapView Instance from other ViewController? (MapBox, Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, viewcontroller

I am using a `ContainerView` within my `MapViewController`, which should be able to trigger the `MapView` in the `MapViewController` for a zooming-method. How can I reference the `MapView` to manipulate it? I did not find any method whatsoever, Android seems to have `getMapAsync`.

Comment: i do not want to down vote your question so be more specific what your issue is and try showing some code as well thanks.

Comment: Be more specific, and provide some code that you've tried before.

Comment: Be more specific with some defined code. Here are some help [MKMapView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapview) and [MKMapViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate). Also check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33857210/access-container-view-child-properties-swift)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue (which was basically communication between two different ViewControllers) by simply implementing a protocol in my MapViewController and setting up a delegate in my PageViewController